How to achieve multiple pagination on the same page in WordPress
I am trying to do basic functionality that could implement multiple paginations for different custom post types on one page.
Initially, I tried to do it by custom pagination. For example, right now I have passed the pagination number as url parameter.
CPT News

/release/?page_news=1
/release/?page_news=2 ...

CPT Resource

/release/?page_resource=1
/release/?page_resource=2 ...

But it looks clumsy.
I was thinking that it should look like
Expected CPT News

/release/news/
/release/news/2 ...

CPT Resource

/release/reource/
/release/reource/2 ...

Please let me know if anyone has a better approach for this situation.

I tried below to make it works.
Created Custom Rewrite

Registering Query Variables: The code adds var1 and var2 as custom query variables using the query_vars filter.

Rewrite Rule: A custom rewrite rule is created that matches URLs in the format /payments-slug/var1-value/var2-value/ and rewrites them to the corresponding index.php with the appropriate query parameters.


<?php
global $wp;
@$wp->add_query_var('var1');
@$wp->add_query_var('var2');

add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_vars');
function wpse12965_query_vars($query_vars)
{
  $query_vars[] = 'var1';
  $query_vars[] = 'var2';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_action('init', 'wpse12065_init');
function wpse12065_init()
{
  global $payments_page_id;
  $post = get_post($payments_page_id);
  $slug = @$post->post_name;
  add_rewrite_rule(
    $slug . '(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
    'index.php?pagename=' . $slug . '&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]',
    'top'
  );
}

For Pagination added below code snippet inside each wp_query

Total Pages & Range: It calculates the total number of pages and sets a range for how many page links to display.

Pagination Loop: It loops through the total pages and generates a list of page numbers as links. The current page is highlighted, while other pages are linked.

Output: Each page link directs to a URL based on the taxonomy name ($taxName) and the page number.


<div class="pagination">
    <div class="moreCenter animateme animated">
        <div class="paginationBox">
            <?php
            $totalPages = $wc_query->max_num_pages;
            $range = 4;
            $showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
                if (1 != $totalPages && (!($i >= $paged + $range + 1 || $i <= $paged - $range - 1) || $totalPages <= $showitems)) {
                    $page_url = get_permalink() . '' . $taxName . '/' . $i;
                    echo ($paged == $i) ? "<span class=\"current\">" . $i . "</span>" : "<a href='" . $page_url . "' class=\"inactive\">" . $i . "</a>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

